# Werewolf trilogy from the 90's

Tags: story-identification, werewolf

I'm looking for the name of a trilogy of werewolf novels from the 90's that were originally part of the Scholastic Book Club's "Thrills and Chills" package. All I recall from the first of the three novels was a boy that discovers he can transform at night, and that other boys in his school can also transform. To avoid the other boys in their werewolf forms at night, he frequently runs and hides in a pond/bog (I think) so that the other wolves can't track him. Eventually, they get wise, and puppy-guard/surround `;)` the pond at night. For some reason, the third book was never available, and I always wanted to conclude that series, even if it's at a kid's reading level.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By pure luck, I finally saw a tiny thumbnail on the Google search for "scholastic werewolf", after trying to figure out the title for years. It's the [Werewolf Chronicles](https://www.goodreads.com/series/64276-werewolf-chronicles) by Rodman Philbrick. All my other searches yielded the "Shiver" series, Twilight (ugh), or WhiteWolf pen-and-paper RPG guides.

[image]

Comment: I was going to ask if these were it! That's what I get for doubting myself!

Comment: @Edlothiad I've been searching for this for years, and 20 minutes after posting my question, a random 200x100px thumbnail sparks a memory.

Comment: Ah well that's the beauty of it, it's happened several times before. And always worth asking here as people here are good at finding a lot of things!

Comment: @Edlothiad: I too saw it, but discounted it because it looked like only Gruff in the town turned, and I was fixated on the idea of his schoolmates being werewolves.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots exactly I wasn't convinced, should've had the guts to post the comment though (unless you'd have then got an answer up first) I'd typed out the comment, then decided it was silly and deleted it.

Comment: @DevNull: You have a high enough rep that you probably know this, but you can accept a self-answer 48 hours after the question was asked.